# Blobstore Library Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I'm following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Uploading_a_Blob

But I have an import error when i try to get BlobStore from library!
[import google.appengine.api.blobstore.*;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srHod.jpg)
Notice that i added the google cloud storage api in my maven dependencies which should to be enough to work but the problem persists!!

How can i resolve this issue??

Comment: Blobstore is **not** part of the cloud storage API, it's built in to App Engine. If you are working in an App Engine project you should not need to add any additional libraries.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it is the same API, i added the dependency          <dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
 <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.17a</version>
</dependency>
Now it works! :D

Comment: great! copying the comment as answer so you can close the question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blobstore is **not** part of the cloud storage API, it's built in to App Engine. If you are working in an App Engine project you should not need to add any additional libraries.